# Subdomain alias of subdomain

Tags: subdomain, alias

On a Linux Plesk server I want the following:

source-sub.domain.com

Aliases:

alias1.domain.com ->source-sub.domain.com

alias2.domain.com ->source-sub.domain.com

alias3.domain.com ->source-sub.domain.com

So I want several subdomains to point to the source sub domain. How do I do this? Can I make a symlink or something?

Answer (score 5):

Just bumped into this myself.

Create a file vhost.conf in the subdomain conf folder:

```
/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/subdomains/source-sub/conf/vhost.conf

# add aliases to that file
ServerAlias  alias1.domain.com
ServerAlias  alias2.domain.com
ServerAlias  alias3.domain.com

# reconfigure PSA's httpdmng
/usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/httpdmng --reconfigure-domain example.com
```

Comment: +1 and an update which might be helpful.  In my Plesk 11 installation there is no conf folder created in each subdomain directory, you would create a vhost.conf in `/var/www/vhosts/source-sub.domain.com/conf/vhost.conf`